# How can I set the encoding of shell-command-on-region output?

Tags: emacs, unicode, utf-8, perl-tidy

I have a small elisp script which applies Perl::Tidy on region or whole file. For reference, here's the script (borrowed from EmacsWiki):

```
(defun perltidy-command(start end)
"The perltidy command we pass markers to."
(shell-command-on-region start 
                       end 
                       "perltidy" 
                       t
                       t
                       (get-buffer-create "*Perltidy Output*")))

(defun perltidy-dwim (arg)
"Perltidy a region of the entire buffer"
(interactive "P")
(let ((point (point)) (start) (end))
(if (and mark-active transient-mark-mode)
    (setq start (region-beginning)
          end (region-end))
  (setq start (point-min)
        end (point-max)))
(perltidy-command start end)
(goto-char point)))

(global-set-key "\C-ct" 'perltidy-dwim)
```

I'm using current Emacs 23.1 for Windows (EmacsW32). The problem I'm having is that if I apply that script on a UTF-8 coded file ("U(Unix)" in the status bar) the output comes back Latin-1 coded, i.e. two or more characters for each non-ASCII source character.

Is there any way I can fix that?

**EDIT**: Problem seems to be solved by using `(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)` in my `init.el`. In anyone has other solutions, go ahead and write them!

Answer (score 3):

Below are from `shell-command-on-region` document

```
To specify a coding system for converting non-ASCII characters
in the input and output to the shell command, use C-x RET c
before this command.  By default, the input (from the current buffer)
is encoded using coding-system specified by `process-coding-system-alist',
falling back to `default-process-coding-system' if no match for COMMAND
is found in `process-coding-system-alist'.
```

During executing, it looks for coding system from `process-coding-system-alist` at first, if it's nil, then looks from `default-process-coding-system`.

If your want to change the encoding, you can add your converting option to `process-coding-system-alist`, below are the content of it.

```
Value: (("\\.dz\\'" no-conversion . no-conversion)
 ...
("\\.elc\\'" . utf-8-emacs)
("\\.utf\\(-8\\)?\\'" . utf-8)
("\\.xml\\'" . xml-find-file-coding-system)
 ...
("" undecided))
```

Or, if you didn't set `process-coding-system-alist`, it's nil, you could assign your encoding option to `default-process-coding-system`,

for example:

```
(setq default-process-coding-system '(utf-8 . utf-8))
```

(If input is encoded as `utf-8`, then output encoded as `utf-8`)

Or

```
(setq default-process-coding-system '(undecided-unix . iso-latin-1-unix))
```

I also wrote a [post](http://zhengdong.me/2012/11/22/coding-system-in-shell-command/) about this if you want details.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the documentation for `shell-command-on-region` (`C-h f shell-command-on-region RET`):

> To specify a coding system for converting non-ASCII characters
>   in the input and output to the shell command, use C-x RET c
>   before this command.  By default, the input (from the current buffer)
>   is encoded in the same coding system that will be used to save the file,
>   `buffer-file-coding-system'.  If the output is going to replace the region,
>   then it is decoded from that same coding system.
>
> The noninteractive arguments are START, END, COMMAND,
>   OUTPUT-BUFFER, REPLACE, ERROR-BUFFER, and DISPLAY-ERROR-BUFFER.
>   Noninteractive callers can specify coding systems by binding
>   `coding-system-for-read' and `coding-system-for-write'.

In other words, you'd do something like

```
(let ((coding-system-for-read 'utf-8-unix))
  (shell-command-on-region ...) )
```

This is untested, not sure what the value of `coding-system-for-read` (or perhaps `-write` instead? or as well?) should be in your case.  I guess you could also utilize the OUTPUT-BUFFER argument and direct the output to a buffer whose coding system is set to what you need it to be.

Another option might be to wiggle the locale in the perltidy invocation, but again, without more information about what you are using now, and no means to experiment on a system similar to yours, I can only hint.